# Microsoft account password criteria

Tags: passwords, account

I have a local account "xyz" defined on multiple computers in my workgroup. The password is all lowercase, but fairly robust.

I want to add a new Windows 8.1 computer that I plan to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro. My Microsoft account is "xyz@mydomain.com". This account's password is not currently the same as that of the local accounts.

I understand that Windows 10 will automatically create a local alias for "xyz".

It would seem that updating the password of the Microsoft account to match the local accounts would allow the new computer to integrate seamlessly.

However, when I enter the lower case password, the Microsoft Account "Change your password" page displays the error message "Please choose a password with  mix of lower and upper case letters, special characters, numbers and symbols".

Is there any way to get the Microsoft nanny to allow me to enter the password I want? If not, I'll have to update the password on each computer, and on any applications on each computer that cares about those credentials. Some of these are offline at the moment, so I'll probably forget (until access fails).

Yeah, I know the answer is going to be 'No', but I just wanted to vent.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you set it up as a local account instead of a microsoft account then you can. Some people don't realize you can still have local only accounts in 8, 8.1, 10. Though if you have to use the microsoft account for various reasons then like you said the answer is no.

Comment: True, but a local account disconnects the computer from the Microsoft account. I can see advantages to having both. 

What I've done at this point is to change the password on all the computers that are online. Next I'm going to do a ZInstall migration from the "old" Win7 computer and see if the files and apps end up being owned by the Microsoft account on the new Win10 computer.

Comment: If I am correct when you do a migration it'll actually create that old account as another account and then not be owned by the new Microsoft account